# Symfony2: Make test.client available in dev environment

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

When using the test environment symfony2 creates a `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client` and registers it as `test.client` service but it is not registered in dev or prod envs. We're writing two kinds of tests: unit tests that use a predefined state of our database and fixtures in the test environment and functional tests that use the local productive database. When I want to use the `Client` to test a route's HTTP behaviour I can only do that in the test environment where I don't have access to the dev database.

How can we reuse the test.client "service" in our dev environment? BTW: It's working when we're copying the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\test.xml` file into our application and include it in the config_dev. Could we also include that file directly from the vendors directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it it any environment as import,

**e.g.**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/test.xml" }
```

**UPDATE:**
Changed it to the correct path.

Comment: yep, the correct import in that case is:     - { resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/test.xml" }